# how to build .html for dynamic route on new nextjs app?

Tags: next.js, build

I need to build .html extension of dynamic route of new nextjs app route . is it posible . my folder structure is (admin)/category/[categoryId]/page.jsx. i have try to use `

```
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const token =
    "my token"
  const response = await fetch(
    "mybackendapi",
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    }
  ).then((res) => res.json());
  console.log(response.results);
  const posts = response.results;

  return posts.map((post) => ({
    categoryId: post.categoryId,
  }));
}

export default function Page({ params }) {
  const { categoryId } = params;
  console.log(categoryId);
  return <>test</>;
}`
```

the build look like

```
`
λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
●  (SSG)     automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)`

 `├ ○ /category                                                                         11.1 kB         157 kB
├ ● /category/[categoryId]  `
```

i need to upload this on s3 by making static. is it possible to change into .html